# How to click on image as a link using RSpec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm using Rspec and Capybara.

How can I write a step to click on an image? I have been unable to find a good way to get Capybara to see the image as a link.

Thanks

Example of html

```
<a title="inGroups" href="/de/users/index/roles-list/serviceID/1112/inGroup/1">
  <img border="0" alt="inGroups" src="/themes/system/images/icon/16/role_activate.png">

<a title="inGroups" href="/de/users/index/roles-list/serviceID/1114/inGroup/1">
   <img border="0" alt="inGroups" src="/themes/system/images/icon/16/role_activate.png">

<a title="notInGroups" href="/de/users/index/roles-list/serviceID/1112/inGroup/0">
   <img border="0" alt="notInGroups" src="/themes/system/images/icon/16/role_deactivate.png">

<a title="notInGroups" href="/de/users/index/roles-list/serviceID/1114/inGroup/0">
    <img border="0" alt="notInGroups" src="/themes/system/images/icon/16/role_deactivate.png">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It shouldn't be any different to clicking a normal link.  I don't see how you would go about selecting an individual link in your example though, without any uniquely identifiable attributes on the link.

If you can't change the markup, you may need to use XPath to actually select the `href` element by the URL e.g.

```
my_link = find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href,'1114/inGroup/1')]")
```

Would give you the first link, and then

```
my_link.click
```

Should click it as normal.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the important thing is that you select the `a` element and click it, not the `img`.

Comment: What driver are you using? That sounds reasonable, but  `Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "a[contains(@href,'1114/inGroup/1')]"
     # (eval):2:in `find' `

Comment: I just edited the XPath to include the '//' prefix - try that

Comment: Awesome! Man, you saved me again... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I put this and works: 
for the index.html got to the show:

```
 find("img[src*='photo03.jpg']").click
```

for the show.html

```
expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='photo03.jpg']")
```